# Why is flutter bloc v8 closing a globally created cubit when I pop some screen that was using this cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

it gives me this error:

Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close.

Comment: Provide some code please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm a bit late but my guess is that you used

```
BlocProvider<ExistingCubit>(
  create: (_) => ExistingCubit(),
)
```

to pass existing cubit to new page.

You should instead use

```
BlocProvider.value(
 value: context.read<ExistingCubit>()
)
```

As the docs say

> `BlocProvider.value` Takes a [value] and a [child] which will have
> access to the [value] via `BlocProvider.of(context)`. When
> `BlocProvider.value` is used, the [Bloc] or [Cubit] **will not be
> automatically closed**. As a result, `BlocProvider.value` should only be
> used for providing existing instances to new subtrees. A new [Bloc] or
> [Cubit] should not be created in `BlocProvider.value`. New instances
> should always be created using the default constructor within the
> [Create] function.